# CSS3 comma separated list (nth-of-class)

Tags: html, css

I have a generated html code as follow.

The rule of thumb:
1) the structure of this html could not be modify, as it is self generated html code by the framework. 
2) Only pure css solution.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="inactive"><span></span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
</div>
```

What i intend to acheive: 
A comma separator as follow.

```
This is active class 1.
This is active class 1, this is active class 2.
This is active class 1, this is active class 2, this is active class 3.
This is active class 2, this is active class 3.
```

But my current outcome seems not able to get this. I am trying to search for last-of-class css selector (to me, everything will be simplified if this selector exist) but it seems that there is no such css selector. But i couldnt think of css logic to workaround. Hope someone could help.

My approach if last of class css exist:

```
.wrapper span > span::after {
   content: ',';
}

.wrapper span:last-child > span::after {
  content: '.';
}

.wrapper span.active:last-of-class > span::after {
  content:'.';
}
```

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/37azymz0/1/)

Comment: Do you mean "last of class" and not "first of class"? Because I don't see how a "first of class" would help here.

Comment: Yup `last-of-class`. thanks for the correction. I have updated the post.

Comment: Can you please stop putting those tags back in? They are not at all relevant. You're not even using HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Switching the logic

#### Targeting odd and even

Use `::before` instead of `::after`; now we just need to remove the first active childs comma when it is **odd** and when it is **even**.

1. Give every span a comma with `::before` (unless it is the first child)
2. Remove the comma when:

   - the first 2 spans are inactive and the 3rd span is active **(odd)**
   - the first span is inactive and the second span is active **(even)**
3. Give the last span the full stop with `::after`.

#### The magic sauce

```
.wrapper > span:not(:first-child) > span::before {
    content: ', ';
}

.wrapper > span.inactive:first-child + span.inactive + span.active > span::before,
.wrapper > span.inactive:first-child + span.active > span::before {
    content: '';
}
```

#### Example

For this example the `display: flex` removes the inline gaps and the `white-space: nowrap` prevents them from wrapping when they hit the viewport edge.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper > span:last-child::after {
    content: '.';
}

.wrapper > span:not(:first-child) > span::before {
    content: ', ';
}

.wrapper > span.inactive:first-child + span.inactive + span.active > span::before,
.wrapper > span.inactive:first-child + span.active > span::before {
    content: '';
}
```

```html
<h2>Random examples</h2>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 4</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 5</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 6</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 8</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 9</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 10</span></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 4</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 8</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 9</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 5</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 9</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 10</span></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 5</span></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 4</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 6</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 9</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
</div>


<h2>
Your examples
</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
    <span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="inactive"><!--<span>This Shouldn't be here, right?</span>--></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
    <span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**: Here's one pure CSS solution:

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="inactive"><span></span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper:after {content:".";}
.active + .active:before { content:", ";}
.wrapper .inactive {display:none;}
```

Here is [my updated CodePen example](http://codepen.io/asonnenshine/pen/kXzGGq)

You might need to adjust the margins/paddings.

Comment: A naïve solution, but the spaces before the commas and period may be unwanted. You *could* hack around this with negative margins, but it is like I said a hack. If the text happens to wrap around the spaces before the punctuation symbols, tough luck.

Comment: Appreciate your effort and comments asonnenshine. But it seems that you make the same assumption as vinicius. Your code would be working in the assumption that the first span child class is active but not the case where the first span child class is inactive (in which they will be a comma in front of the line)

Comment: can you provide an HTML snippet for the situation you mentioned? will the inactive spans always be empty?

Answer (score -1):

Using pure css you can do it with the following:

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}
.active:not(:nth-child(1) ) > span:before{
  content: ', ';
}
.wrapper:after{
  content: '.';
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="inactive"></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
<span class="inactive"></span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 1</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 2</span></span>
<span class="active"><span>This is active class 3</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't even come *close*. The commas are incorrectly placed, and there are no periods.

Comment: Appreciate your effort and comments vinicius. Your code would be working in the assumption that the first span child class is `active` but not the case where the first span child class is `inactive`. https://jsfiddle.net/suw9wmbq/

Comment: Ok. this code is bullet proof now. :D Try to break it. :)